# overflow error when reading file from external drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, binarystream

I'm seeing an Overflow Error when trying to read a binary stream from an external SSD:

```
with open(self.path, "rb") as input_file:
  input_file.seek(offset)
  data = input_file.read(chunk_bytes)
```

the `read` method call sporadically results in the following exception:

```
OSError: [Errno 34] Result too large
```

The error is supposed to signify the number being too large, but `chunk_bytes` is only 8 MB, so I can't see how that can be the issue.

A couple of things to note:

1. if I copy the contents from the external drive onto my local drive, I never run into this error
2. when reading from external drive, this error happens sometimes but not others, it's indeterministic

What could be causing the issue?

Edit: I'm using Mac OS Monterey, the SSD is formatted with HFS+

Comment: Are you sure that's coming from `read` and not `seek`?

Comment: Although neither read nor seek should have a problem with going beyond the end of the file. If you try to read more than is available it just returns what it can.

Comment: yes, the traceback shows me that the exception is raised at `read`

Comment: What operating system are you on? I can't find any documentation that says that Linux read() can return the ERANGE error.

Comment: Mac OS Monterey. Also edited my question to add that info

Comment: I was hoping it was something like Unix-like, e.g. Windows.